# VB.net Conditional String Split/Parse using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, string, linq

I need to parse and separate input strings using VB.NET. Split method works in Example 1, but my problem is when I need to “skip” a space if the following value isn’t in the list like Example2. My code works as expected for String1 using Split, but it fails my needs when it outputs EXT1000 and 3 as individual values - they should be part of the original string if not found in the list.
I would prefer to keep it in Linq if possible. Generate some type of collection to be used for later manipulation. The main output will end up with a For Each “Results” WriteLine in text file.

> `list = {“AB”, “CD”, “EFG”, “HI”, …. “MN”, “OP”, “QR”…}`

(results from LINQ from external file. I’m not using it in my code yet, but I think I’ll need to incorporate some comparison)

- String1 = “**AB CD5 EFG10 HI2 AB**” (mC..Value.Split)
- Results1: (multiCode)
- **AB** (m)
- **CD5** (m)
- **EFG10** (m)
- **HI2** (m)
- **AB** (m)
- String2 = “**MN3 MN4 OP8 EXT1000 QR 3**”
- Results2:
- **MN3**
- **MN4**
- **OP8 EXT1000** (should skip space because “EXT” isn’t in list)
- **QR 3** (should skip space because “3” isn’t in list)

  Dim multiPoint As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
                  From mPoint In xdoc....Reverse

  Dim multiCode = _
              From mC In multiPoint _
                  From m In mC..Value.Split _
                  Select m

  For Each cd In multiCode
              Console.WriteLine(cd)
  Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim MasterList As String() = {"AB", "CD", "EFG", "HI", "MN", "OP", "QR"}

Dim OtherList As String() = {"AB3", "CD4", "EFG1000", "3"}

Dim DesiredList As String() = (From strValueInMasterList As String In MasterList _
                               From strValueFromOtherList As String In OtherList _
                               Where strValueFromOtherList.StartsWith(strValueInMasterList) _
                               Select strValueFromOtherList).ToArray()
```